# What is the best way to create web-service and admin-site for single database?

Tags: django

I want to create web-service and admin-site that use common database. 
The database contains tables with the information about goods.

The task of web-service is to process user requests on different protocols (xmpp, icq, etc.) getting the data from database and updating it (for ex. sell or see goods info). The task of admin-site is to show the statistics of this requests and admin the database(show tables, insert rows, backup, etc.)

For creating a site I choose django.
And here is the dilemma. On one hand, it is probably better to separate site from service. On the other hand, django has perfect tools to work with DB, and its models may probably give an opportunity to avoid copy-paste. But I haven't found any application containing both service and site, and so I doubt if it is normal or possible at all.

Any thoughts about it highly appreciated: create or not service and site in one application, or what would be the better way for this model.

Answer (score 1):

Django is built for web development. It has a very robust `Http` library which can `respond` in variety of formats like `JSON,javascript..` etc, and as you mentioned django has `ORM` to deal with database, which is object oriented.

Whether we can build site and service with django?.

Hear's how I look at this you can do your admin with statistics and everything using     `django-admin` and you can use the django's `views` and `url's` to write your web services.

**Views.py:**

```
def mywebservice(request):
    ....
    return HttpResponse(data,mimetype)
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
(r'^mywebservice/$','myapp.views.mywebservice')
```

For detailed examples, a quick google search will take you to [this](http://andrewwilkinson.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/building-better-web-services-with-django-part-1/) page.

Comment: Its interesting, but the task is to use different protocols (xmpp, icq, etc.), not the different response formats.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the range of protocols but I think there are packages like `django-xmpp` and `agiliq/django-pubsub` which kinda respond in `xmpp` you can do something similar.